# Nomear polígonos no google maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

Estou usando uma api do google maps para gerar alguns talhões e eu gostaria de gerar os nomes deles no próprio polígono assim que eu abrir o mapa ao invés de gerar ele no balão.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código que gera os polignos :

```
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: -15.968679, lng: -54.965524},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
  var triangleCoords1 = [
{lat: -15.968679, lng: -54.965524},
{lat: -15.968589, lng: -54.965446}, 
{lat: -15.968447, lng: -54.965387}, 
{lat: -15.968254, lng: -54.965410}, 
{lat: -15.968099, lng: -54.965520}, 
{lat: -15.968019, lng: -54.965673},
{lat: -15.968029, lng: -54.965917},
{lat: -15.968111, lng: -54.966056}, 
{lat: -15.968237, lng: -54.966139},
{lat: -15.968454, lng: -54.966174},
{lat: -15.968647, lng: -54.966080},
{lat: -15.968793, lng: -54.965872},
{lat: -15.968759, lng: -54.965633},
{lat: -15.968679, lng: -54.965524}

  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords1,
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  bermudaTriangle1.setMap(map);
```

Eu tentei usar isso mas não funcionou tambem.

```
font="20px Georgia";
strokeText("Texto",10,50);
```

Como eu faria para imprimir os nomes direto no polígono sem precisar abrir o balão?